# Excel 2010 VBA repeating formula(s) in specified cells based on defined variables

Tags: excel, vba, variables, repeat

Also asked over [here](http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=173201).

I have an export with "reporting segments" that are ALWAYS 22 rows each and the first one always starts in row 5 when brought into Excel. A document where the last row (containing an 'End of Report' special character) is 247 would have 11 reporting segments.

Within each reporting segment, there are two different formulas needed.

For the first reporting segment, always located in rows A5 thru J27:

Using VBA in Excel 2010, I need to put FORMULA1 in all cells of the range (D5:D15 dragged out to H5:H10(not 15) and D18) and FORMULA2 in cells (F20:F22,J20:J22).

Then I need to **repeat** that **vTaskCount** number of times (number of segments) and at intervals of 22 (segment repeater offset). Some reports may have 2 segments, some might have 50, but the structure is always identical. I'm hoping that since I can tell it the number of times to repeat the process, that it will make it simpler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
sub whatever()
dim lNumSegs as long, lLoop as long

lNumSegs=(cells(rows.count,1).end(xlup).row-5)/22

for lLoop =1 to lnumsegs
   range(D5:D15).offset((lloop-1)*22).formular1c1="=FOrmula1"
   range(H5:H10).offset((lloop-1)*22).formular1c1="=FOrmula1"
   range(D18).offset((lloop-1)*22).formular1c1="=FOrmula1"

   range("F20:F22,J20:J22").offset((lloop-1)*22).formular1c1="=FOrmula2"
next lloop

end sub
```

Comment: That's much simpler than what I was trying to tweak (http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=150099) - I'll give it the check mark as soon as I make it work. Thanks!

Comment: Set the offset to *22 instead of *11 (not half of the repeat) and it worked like a charm. THANK YOU!